# Is there any way around using temporary files when you want to extract discontinuous lines?

Tags: bash, sed

Here's a bash script I wrote to get the weather for Boston (the weather-util command recently broke for Boston, MA):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Shows the weather forecast for Boston, MA

TMPFILE=${TMPDIR-/tmp}/ne_weather.$$
curl -s 'http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/forecasts/state/ma/maz007.txt' > $TMPFILE
sed -n '/^TAB/,+11p' < $TMPFILE
sed -n '/BOSTON/,+3p' < $TMPFILE
rm $TMPFILE
```

I am using a temp file because I can't figure out how to use `sed` on the output of `curl` in one pass. Any suggestions for doing this without resorting to a temporary file? Or is it perfectly OK?

Comment: A single pass is more elegant and has less possibility for littering the file system. But a temp file is perfectly OK and is certainly a lot easier to debug and probably maintain (i.e. what happens when you need like 10 different lines? one enormo `sed` command?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output of `curl` into `sed`:

```
curl -s 'http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/forecasts/state/ma/maz007.txt' | sed -n '/^TAB/,+11p; /BOSTON/,+3p'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a temp file, just display?

```
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        "TAB"* )
        echo "->$line";
        for i in {1..11};do read -r line;echo "->$line"; done
        ;;
        "BOSTON"* )
        echo "$line"
        for i in {1..3}; do read -r line ; echo "$line";done
        ;;
    esac
done < <(curl -s 'http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/forecasts/state/ma/maz007.txt')
```